# Directory data change observer in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications, observer-pattern

Hi i know that in NSWorkspace is a method that check if data is changed (noteFileSystemChanged:), but i was wondering if there is a possibility to automaticly observe for data change on specified path (ex. new file in directory).

Thanks for reply !

Comment: `noteFileSystemChanged:` doesn't ask whether the file-system has changed; it tells other applications that it has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [FSEvents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) (file system events) API. You can ask to be notified of file- or folder-level changes... [puny human](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_recurring_characters_in_Futurama#Lrrr)!

Comment: Ha, but then again this return only directory in which event occured... Do You now a way to get files that were added, edited or something :?